# How to make a key for object from another object?

Tags: php, object

I have:

```
$product = Product::where('id', $productId)->first();
```

I need to add a new row in object `$this->items`, where the key of object will be `$product->id`. This is bad syntaxis, but something like this:

```
$this->items->$product->id = (object)['name' => $product->name]
```

How to do it with the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$this->items` is an array, you should use

```
$this->items[$product->id] = (object)['name' => $product->name] ;
```

If it is an object, you should use a temporary variable before :

```
$tmp_id = $product->id ;
$this->items->$tmp_id = (object)['name' => $product->name] ;
```

or use brackets :

```
$this->items->{$product->id} = (object)['name' => $product->name] ;
```

**Why?**

Because `$this->items->$product->id` will be interpreted to get `id` of `$this->items->$product` instead of evaluate `$product->id` before.